# Is it possible to have more than one XmlnsPrefix inside same assembly?

Tags: wpf, xaml, markup

I am developing a custom WPF controls library which includes controls converters, triggers and behaviors distributed among appropriate namespaces. I know how to define XmlnsDefinition, and XmlnsPrefix assembly information and using that extensively. Hwta I want to do is to devine XmlnsPrefix for each namespace inside same assembli so ForExample if a have declaration like this

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.taicodev.com/winfx/2010/xaml/presentation", "TaicoControl")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.taicodev.com/winfx/2010/xaml/presentation", "CuratioCMS.Client.UI.Converters")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.taicodev.com/winfx/2010/xaml/presentation", "CuratioCMS.Client.UI.Controls")]
```

I want to leave TaicoControl but for Converters use TaicoConverter prefix automatically

is that possible and how can achieve that without partitioning assembly in many different assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 2 different CLR namespaces to use 2 different xmlns prefixes then you need to define the xmlnsdefinition for each CLR namespace such that it uses a different URI and then define an xmlnsprefix for each unique URI.

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.taicodev.com/winfx/2010/xaml/presentation", "TaicoControl")]
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.taicodev.com/winfx/2010/xaml/presentation/converters", "TaicoConverters")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.taicodev.com/winfx/2010/xaml/presentation/converters", "CuratioCMS.Client.UI.Converters")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.taicodev.com/winfx/2010/xaml/presentation", "CuratioCMS.Client.UI.Controls")]
```

Comment: That's what really works, but is there a way to have one XmlnsDefinition as in my situation there are some nested namespaces as well? I mean what u suggested i works 100% but forces to add to XAML extra xmlns:ExConverter

Comment: Isn't that what you were asking for? That the converters have a separate xmlns prefix? I mean the original way you had everything would be available under the single xmlns prefix. You could keep what you had and also define the xmlns definition and xmlns prefix attributes for the converters if you are looking to offer a way for someone to be able to access the converters under the main xmlns prefix and also under a separate xmlns prefix specific to converters.